# How to format a column in Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Have a Spark DataFrame call df like this:

```
+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
|  1|  6|
|  2|  7|
|  3|  8|
|  4|  9|
|  5| 10|
|  6| 11|
|  7| 12|
|  8| 13|
|  9| 14|
+---+---+
```

and I want to generate a new DataFrame to get the fraction of c1 and c2, the result should be like this:

```
+---+---+------+
| c1| c2|    c3|
+---+---+------+
|  9| 14|0.6429|
|  8| 13|0.6154|
|  7| 12|0.5833|
|  6| 11|0.5455|
|  5| 10|0.5000|
|  4|  9|0.4444|
|  3|  8|0.3750|
|  2|  7|0.2857|
|  1|  6|0.1667|
+---+---+------+
```

However, when I use the code

```
res.withColumn("c3", col("c1")/col("c2")).orderBy(col("c3").desc).show()
```

I got:

```
+---+---+-------------------+
| c1| c2|                 c3|
+---+---+-------------------+
|  9| 14| 0.6428571428571429|
|  8| 13| 0.6153846153846154|
|  7| 12| 0.5833333333333334|
|  6| 11| 0.5454545454545454|
|  5| 10|                0.5|
|  4|  9| 0.4444444444444444|
|  3|  8|              0.375|
|  2|  7| 0.2857142857142857|
|  1|  6|0.16666666666666666|
+---+---+-------------------+
```

How to format c3 to the desired format without having to generate another DataFrame? (I want to get the result from df in just one line of code, how can i achieve this?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [format_number](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#format_number(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20int)) function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
res.withColumn("c3", format_number(col("c1")/col("c2"), 4)).orderBy(col("c3").desc).show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could also cast the result to the correct `DecimalType()`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._                                                                   

res.withColumn("c3", (col("c1")/col("c2"))
   .cast(DecimalType(4,4)))
   .orderBy(col("c3").desc).show()
```