# How to retain leading zero in spark data frame column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, double

Here is my data

```
Source.organizationId|^|Source.sourceId|^|FilingDateTime|^|SourceTypeCode|^|DocumentId|^|Dcn|^|DocFormat|^|StatementDate|^|IsFilingDateTimeEstimated|^|ContainsPreliminaryData|^|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate|^|CumulativeAdjustmentFactor|^|ContainsRestatement|^|FilingDateTimeUTCOffset|^|ThirdPartySourceCode|^|ThirdPartySourcePriority|^|SourceTypeId|^|ThirdPartySourceCodeId|^|FFAction|!|
4295858966|^|62|^|2017-08-31T11:00:00Z|^|AUTINR|^|44819867|^|cr06305583|^|PDFNTV|^|2017-06-30T00:00:00Z|^|False|^|False|^|2017-06-30T00:00:00Z|^|1.00000|^|False|^|60|^|SS |^|1|^|3011930|^|1000716240|^|I|!|
```

For the column `CumulativeAdjustmentFactor` value is `1.00000` .
When i load and print it i get

```
1.0
```

How to retain the same value?

Schema is below

```
root
 |-- Source_organizationId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Source_sourceId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- FilingDateTime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SourceTypeCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DocumentId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Dcn: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DocFormat: string (nullable = true)
 |-- StatementDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsFilingDateTimeEstimated: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- ContainsPreliminaryData: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CumulativeAdjustmentFactor: double (nullable = true)
 |-- ContainsRestatement: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- FilingDateTimeUTCOffset: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ThirdPartySourceCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ThirdPartySourcePriority: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- SourceTypeId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ThirdPartySourceCodeId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- FFAction: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DataPartition: string (nullable = true)
```

When i print i get below output

```
+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------+----------+--------+---------+--------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------+----------------------+--------+-------------+
|Source_organizationId|Source_sourceId|      FilingDateTime|SourceTypeCode|DocumentId|     Dcn|DocFormat|       StatementDate|IsFilingDateTimeEstimated|ContainsPreliminaryData|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate|CumulativeAdjustmentFactor|ContainsRestatement|FilingDateTimeUTCOffset|ThirdPartySourceCode|ThirdPartySourcePriority|SourceTypeId|ThirdPartySourceCodeId|FFAction|DataPartition|
+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------+----------+--------+---------+--------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------+----------------------+--------+-------------+
|           4295880476|            228|2016-00-28T03:00:00Z|        JPNARA|      null|    null|     null|2016-00-31T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2016-00-31T12:00:00Z|                       1.0|              false|                    540|                 SS |                       1|     3012415|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295876886|            312|2014-00-25T12:00:00Z|        JPNARA|      null|    null|     null|2014-00-31T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2015-00-31T12:00:00Z|                       5.0|              false|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3012415|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295878485|             12|2001-00-14T12:00:00Z|        JPNINR|      null|    null|     null|2001-00-30T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2001-00-30T12:00:00Z|                       0.5|              false|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3012418|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295878485|             17|2002-00-14T12:00:00Z|        JPNINR|      null|    null|     null|2002-00-30T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2002-00-30T12:00:00Z|                       0.5|              false|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3012418|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295878485|             46|2006-00-26T12:00:00Z|        JPNINR|      null|    null|     null|2005-00-31T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2005-00-31T12:00:00Z|                       0.5|               true|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3012418|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295876080|            114|2012-00-10T12:00:00Z|        JPNINR|      null|    null|     null|2012-00-01T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2012-00-01T12:00:00Z|                       0.5|              false|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3012418|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295880487|              7|2001-00-22T12:00:00Z|        JPNINR|      null|    null|     null|2001-00-30T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2001-00-30T12:00:00Z|                      null|              false|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3012418|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295880487|              9|2002-00-14T12:00:00Z|        JPNINR|      null|    null|     null|2002-00-30T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2002-00-30T12:00:00Z|                      null|              false|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3012418|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295880487|             10|2002-00-20T12:00:00Z|        JPNINR|      null|    null|     null|2002-00-30T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2002-00-30T12:00:00Z|                      null|              false|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3012418|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295880534|            128|2012-00-04T12:00:00Z|        JPNINR|      null|    null|     null|2012-00-01T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2012-00-01T12:00:00Z|                       1.0|              false|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3012418|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295877413|            173|2014-00-28T03:00:00Z|           20F|  34601135|14723203|  ASFILED|2013-00-31T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2013-00-31T12:00:00Z|                       1.0|              false|                    540|                 SS |                       1|     3011845|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295878485|             21|2003-00-30T12:00:00Z|           20F|   1210145|    null|     null|2003-00-31T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2003-00-31T12:00:00Z|                       0.5|              false|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3011845|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295878485|             28|2004-00-29T12:00:00Z|           20F|   3866028|    null|     null|2004-00-31T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2004-00-31T12:00:00Z|                       0.5|              false|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3011845|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295878485|             38|2005-00-29T12:00:00Z|           20F|   5538099|    null|     null|2005-00-31T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2005-00-31T12:00:00Z|                       0.5|              false|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3011845|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295878485|             49|2006-00-28T12:00:00Z|           20F|   7351897|    null|     null|2006-00-31T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2006-00-31T12:00:00Z|                       0.5|              false|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3011845|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295878485|             55|2007-00-28T12:00:00Z|           20F|   8834460|    null|     null|2007-00-31T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2007-00-31T12:00:00Z|                      null|              false|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3011845|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295878485|            177|2015-00-25T03:00:00Z|           20F|  38086474|15950616|  ASFILED|2015-00-31T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2015-00-31T12:00:00Z|                       1.0|              false|                    540|                 SS |                       1|     3011845|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295878485|             11|2001-00-04T12:00:00Z|           20F|      null|    null|     null|2001-00-31T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2001-00-31T12:00:00Z|                       0.5|               true|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3011845|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295878485|             16|2002-00-20T12:00:00Z|           20F|   3556586|    null|     null|2002-00-31T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2002-00-31T12:00:00Z|                       0.5|              false|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3011845|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
|           4295878485|             57|2007-00-25T12:00:00Z|           6K0|   8923021|    null|     null|2007-00-30T12:00:00Z|                    false|                  false|       2007-00-30T12:00:00Z|                      null|              false|                      0|                 SS |                       1|     3011851|            1000716240|       I|        Japan|
+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------+----------+--------+---------+--------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------+----------------------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: read it as text file or create a schema with that field as string and you should be fine. you are treating it as double. thats the main problem

Answer (score 0):

It can not be done because your `CumulativeAdjustmentFactor` column type is `double`, the `show` method simply call the `toString` of `double`.

```
> 1.0000.toString
1.0
```

It's inherent behavior of `double`.

You can convert to `string` type to display full value.

Comment: I have converted it to string type but still getting same `1.0`

Comment: Sorry, I see. I will dig deep about it. And,btw where did you obtain the dataframe, from storage, derive form another dataframe or smt else ???

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert it to a string, there's the format_number method that's discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955413/how-to-format-a-column-in-spark-dataframe) with examples. This method takes a number for the precision you want, and will retains trailing zeros in the pyspark implementation, scala spark I haven't tested it though.